# Wordpress plugin editor on mobile typing bug

Tags: wordpress, plugins, editor

I love to do some "on the go" coding in the wordpress backend in my spare time.

The situation:
When editing theme or plugin files in the theme editor or plugin editor on my mobile device (android), whenever I try to type on a new line in the file, the character gets automatically "backspaced".

The editor does work when editing existing lines of code, or copy and pasting it in.

When using a bluetooth keyboard the editor works fine too.

There doesn't seem to be any jquery related errors either.

Does anyone know the root of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to report this as a bug, WordPress is open source. Bugs will be handled by priority by many volunteers.

You can read more about submitting a bug and what you need to yourself when submitting one.

See: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/

Make sure to read the page thoroughly before submitting a "bug".